# What is the physical interpretation of the free current ($(K_f\times \hat{n})$)?

Tags: electromagnetism

The diagram below, taken from Griffiths is of an Amperian loop on a surface current in matter. Why is it that the free current is perpendicular to the surface current?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free current is not perpendicular to the surface current. The surface current K here is same as free current. Vector n denotes normal to the surface and has nothing to do with current. the three arrows show the direction of free current.

Comment: Then why is there a vector labeled $\vec{I}$ going perpendicular to the surface current.

Comment: Its not current its the length of the rectangular loop. There are no currents perpendicular to surface current for sure.